# $(document).ready(function(){ code }); not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I know this has been asked multiple times, but neither of the answers seem to help me.

I've been almost two days trying to get around this but I haven't been able to figure out what's going on.

I have the following code:

```
alert('Before document.ready');
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert('Actual document.ready');

  addNumberValidation($("#quantity"), $("#quantityError"));
  addNumberValidation($("#price"), $("#priceError"));

  $("#form").submit(function(){ 
    var quantityValid = validar( $("#quantity"), $("#quantityError") );
    var priceValid= validar( $("#price"), $("#priceError"));
    var formValid = quantityValid && priceValid;
    return formValid ;
  });
});

function addNumberValidation(mainElement, errorElement) {
  mainElement.keyup(function () {
    validate($(this), errorElement);
  });
}

function validate( mainElement, errorElement) {
  var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
  var result = false;
  if ( mainElement.val().match(regex)) {
    errorElement.text('');
    result = true;
  } else {
    errorElement.text('Must be a number');
    result = true;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The script is getting loaded correctly because the "Before document.ready" alert is getting called correctly. Also, jQuery is getting loaded as well because other js code is executing properly.

My console shows no error whatsoever and the script under the sources tab in Chrome is complete.

I documented the functions to see if there was something wrong with that and it still didn't work.

Any insights of what could be going on?

Comment: Try to move your 2 functions within the document.ready statement...

Comment: Presumably the evidence that the "ready" handler isn't being called is that the `alert()` is not happening. If that's the case, it doesn't matter where the other two functions are.

Comment: Where's the `validar()` function?

Comment: what does `validar` return?

Comment: No error in the console, and document.ready not being executed seems highly unlikely, are you sure about this, and is the code exactly as posted ?

Comment: Provide online link where this issue can be checked

Comment: Try type this in your console: `$===jQuery`. If the result is false you you have something other than jQuery stored in the variable.

Comment: @null Ya but wouldn't explain the alert not to be called

Comment: Another library was making the issue. When I removed that library the document.ready was actually called. As for the "validar()" was because I translated everything folr the question and missed that one. It's the validate function

Comment: @A.Wolff Depends.. `$=function(){return {ready:function() {}}}`... `$(document).ready(function() { /* never called */ });`

Comment: @null Ya but it would be a really specific case :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Another library was making a conflict that avoided the document.ready to get called

Comment: At least tell us which library? And anyway you should have error in console

Comment: It was select2. It was throwing an error that I saw in other places where document.ready actually worked so I ignored it, but apparently this was no the case.

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad. I That was no error besides the ones I already had before that worked. Won't happen again. Sorry.